# How much suction force does it take to pull a human's brain out of their skull?

Tags: biology, brain

I have a [Krang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krang)-like character/parasite that lives in hollowed-out human heads and pilots the body around like a meat mecha. They're essentially a brain with sensory organs and rudimentary manipulators/limbs attached.

At the end of each long, hard day of being an evil little bastard, they like to "disembark" via suction tube; to do this, they hinge the top of the head open, use their host body's limbs to attach a tube to it, and suck themselves out.

How much suction force would be required to completely extract a human brain from a circular gap in the skull ~6 centimeters in diameter? Assume that this entity is, for all intents and purposes, a human brain in terms of consistency/texture/malleability/etc.

Comment: Uh, does it matter? Can you not just declare it to be "enough suction" via authorial fiat and be done with it? It isn't obvious to me how much brain suction pressure/forces add to your story or setting.

Comment: Complete extraction in one go won't happen anyway. The brain would be torn into smaller fragments. Because the diameter of several brain parts is larger than 6 centimeters, connective tissue will be severed and brain parts will fall back into the victim's head. While doing its brain sucking, your ninja turtle parasite will need to dig around, grab parts of the brain separately and suck multiple times.

Comment: non sequitur but I would think through the nose would be the easier way, like in Egyptian mummification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how quickly you want to pull out.

Gruesome details apart, your question boils down to

> What is the pressure drop for a fluid flowing through a hole of given diameter?

To answer this, refer to this [equations](https://neutrium.net/fluid-flow/cv-versus-orifice-size/)

> The pressure drop or flow rate through a valve or orifice plate is typically calculated using the a flow coefficient, $C_v$
>
> $C_v=46250.9C_dD_0^2$ which for a diameter of 6 mm gives $C_v=1$

From [here](https://neutrium.net/fluid-flow/pressure-loss-cv-and-kv-method/)

> Cv relates to pressure drop and flow rate via the following expression
>
> $C_v=0.00694Q \sqrt{\rho/ \Delta P \cdot 999}$
>
> Where Q is in L/min, ρ is in kg/m3 and ΔP is in bar

Once you decide how quickly you want to get out, you have settled on your Q, then you just need to apply the formula.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the flow rate must depend somehow on the viscosity of the fluid, and the viscosity of the brain is quite high. Which would put a limit on the flow rate, because the suction cannot exceed 1 bar for the obvious reason.

Comment: I love that someone can ask about brain suction in this stack and then get an answer with an equation for it.